# How can i use the Result of an HTTP request (zip file) in the body of another http request?

Tags: jmeter

I have two HTTP requests (Export and Import).
The result of the "Export" request is a zip file and i want to use that downloaded file in the body of the "Import" request.
Does anyone have an idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the Export response look like? What is the mime type?

Comment: The response Body of the `Export` request is void and the mime type is application/zip .

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be storing the file to your drive via [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener added as a child of the `Export` request and then specifying the path to the stored file in the "Files Upload" section of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for the `Import` request

Example test plan structure:

[image]

More information: [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter/)

However if your scenario is different and you need to do this in memory, you can read the zip file contents into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and the following regular expression:

```
(?s)(^.*)
```

once done you will be able to use the associated JMeter Variable where required.

Comment: I have added the `Save Responses to a file` listener and it creates a .zip file in the bin folder.
However, that zip file is corrupted.